# How to correctly mount code in docker for development

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose

I develop a flask application in a docker container. A minimal example of my code has the following structure:

```
+- myproject
   +- Flask-App
      +- src
         +- __init__.py
      +-__init__.py
      +- Dockerfile
      +- requirements.txt
      +- wsgi.py
+- docker-compose.yml
```

> I made the example even more minimalistic (see second edit)

Since, I am currently developing the application, I want to add `src` as a volume to my container. Without mounting the volume, I have to rebuild the container every time. Whenever I add the volume, this error is raised:

```
Attaching to flask
flask    | Traceback (most recent call last):
flask    |   File "wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
flask    |     from src import create_app
flask    | ImportError: cannot import name 'create_app' from 'src' (unknown location)
flask exited with code 1
```

Without the `volume` command in `docker-compose.yml`, the code runs. Can you please explain how I can circumvent this problem?

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  flask:
    build:
      context: ./Flask-App
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: flask
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
    volumes:                      # produces error
      - ./src/:/home/appuser/src/ # produces error
```

**Flask-App/wsgi.py**

```
from src import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

**Flask-App/requirements.txt**

```
Flask==1.1.1
```

**Flask-App/Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.7.3-stretch

COPY ./requirements.txt /tmp/
RUN pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt

RUN useradd --home /home/appuser appuser

WORKDIR /home/appuser
USER appuser

COPY ./ ./

# Run the application
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["wsgi.py"]
```

**Flask-App/src/__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask


def create_app():

    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        return "Hello World"

    return app
```

## EDIT 1

**Flask-App/Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.7.3-stretch

COPY ./requirements.txt /tmp/
RUN pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt

RUN useradd --home /home/appuser appuser

WORKDIR /home/appuser
USER appuser

COPY ./ ./
RUN echo $(ls -alt /home/appuser)  # newly added
# Run the application
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["wsgi.py"]
```

**Output of `echo ls`**

```
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Oct 22 11:55 .
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 345 Oct 22 11:55 Dockerfile
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 117 Oct 22 11:25 wsgi.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Oct 22 11:17 __init__.py
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 22 11:17 src 
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Oct 21 11:15 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12 Oct 21 11:14 requirements.txt
```

## EDIT 2

Ok, I made it even more minimalistic. This example does not need Flask at all. When I mount the volume, the program raises again an error

```
flask_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
flask_1  |   File "app.py", line 1, in <module>
flask_1  |     from src import create_app
flask_1  | ImportError: cannot import name 'create_app' from 'src' (unknown location)
```

Below, I added again all the files to reproduce the error.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  flask:
    build:
      context: ./Flask-App
    volumes:
      - ./Flask-App/src:/usr/src/app/sr
```

**Flask-App/src/__init__.py**

```py
class MyTest:

    def my_print_fnc(self):
        print("Hello World")


def create_app():
    return MyTest()
```

**Flask-App/app.py** (replaces `wsgi.py`)

```py
from src import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.my_print_fnc()
```

**Flask-App/Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.7.3-stretch

COPY . /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app


# Run the application
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "app.py"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  flask:
    build:
      context: ./Flask-App
    volumes:
      - ./Flask-App/src:/usr/src/app/src
```

Comment: Why are you attaching `src` folder instead of `Flask-App` folder? Isn't that the root folder of your flask project?

Comment: I think it does not make a big difference. I am just attaching `./Flask-App/src` instead of `./Flask-App/` since all the source code is in `src`. However, this does not solve the issue. With your suggestion, I get an other error: `flask    | python: can't open file 'wsgi.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: Do I have to change the permissions of the content in `Flask-App/`. It is all owned by `root` but I run my commands as `appuser`.

Comment: Yeah, try that too

Comment: I can not find how to change the permission of a mounted volume under Windows 10 as host system?

Comment: The output of `ls` of `/home/appuser` that you posted shows that inside docker container, the files belong to `root`. But you are trying to run them as `appuser`

Comment: When I comment out `USER appuser`, the error persists.

Comment: I don't know flask so I can't fully help. Revise your knowledge quickly 1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YFl2mCHdv24 & 2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qw9zlE3t8Ko and see if you can solve this

Comment: @eMad Thank you for the suggestion. I removed all Flask related parts and it still raises an error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201309/discussion-between-emad-and-mol1narius).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the problem of my code. It is in `Flask-App/Dockerfile`. The copy command does not take the **WORKDIR** into consideration.

**Flask-App/Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.7.3-stretch

COPY ./requirements.txt /tmp/
RUN pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt

RUN useradd --home /home/appuser appuser

WORKDIR /home/appuser
USER appuser

COPY . /home/appuser            # <- specify the absolute path

# Run the application
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["wsgi.py"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  flask:
    build:
      context: ./Flask-App
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: flask
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - "./Flask-App/src/:/home/appuser/src"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your docker-compose.yml file, espcially the way you are mounting the volumes. Change that to:

```
volumes: :
      - './Flask-App:/home/appuser'
```

Comment: After adding `volumes: - './Flask-App/src:/home/appuser/src'` into `docker-compose`, the error persists. :(

Comment: Thank you for making it more specific. However, I still receive the following error: `flask    | python: can't open file 'wsgi.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: Try setting an environment variable to your python path.

Comment: Like so: ```PYTHONPATH=/home/cinch/Develop/cinch/```. Hope that is helpful